# Digitize a Floor Map with Easy Image Processing Techniques?

Tags: image-processing

I am currently working on a project, where I need a huge amount of trajectories as the input data to test my algorithm. I have devised a draft the algorithm and now wish to do some rough testing on it before turning the draft into the final version. For this purpose, I need a lot of trajectories.

In this trial-and-error phase, due to the time limit, spending a lot of energy and time in collecting a huge bunch of trajectories is not a wise option. Therefore, **I am trying to generate some trajectories** to simulate first. Using computer to generate is easy, fast and cheap.

Obviously, a series of random points is NOT acceptable. **The trajectories can be random but have to be reasonable.** e.g. one cannot penetrate the walls or just randomly spin around.

Let's say I wish to generate the trajectories within this indoor map.

[image]

Some basic ideas that I have are as follows:

1. Random choose a point as the start point and another as the end point. These two points must be chosen among the reachable ones.
2. Generate a trajectory that does not penetrate the wall and roughly goes along the walls. In this case all the walls are either vertical or horizontal. So here the trajectories are all more or less straight.

I feel very reluctant to just manually "digitize" the `.png` map into the point representation. Doing that is very time  consuming. **Can I use some easy image processing techniques to "digitize" the map for my trajectory generation purpose?**

Can I just somewhat extract the information, like expressing all the inaccessible areas as in terms of points, from the `.png` file? I know Python, by the way.

Comment: For my bachelor's thesis, I was developing something similar. Initially I worked with a PDF overlaid on to the map view. Apple had a sample project in this manner. Then I switched to Google Maps to a place with native indoor support. Both times, I placed nodes into the available routes as references to be able to determine a meaningful walking path. Did you had any advancements?